# Involutive (up to precision) operations "dataframe to csv" and "csv to dataframe"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a numerically really intensive vectorized python function `def f(x,y)` in two variables that I evaluate (with `frompyfunc` and broadcasting) on a np.array `X = [x0, ...., xN-1]` of `x`'s and a np.array `Y = [y0, ...., yM-1]` of `y`'s with N,M between 5 and 10 thousands. This  returns as result a 2D np.array `Z` of shape (N,M) containing `z[i,j]`'s such that `z[i,j] = f(X[i], Y[j])` for all i and j. The function `f` is optimized and this already takes roughly 45 minutes. As I then write, debug, profile code using `Z`, I want to "save" the "matrix" `Z` in a csv file, in this kind of format :

```
    0.25        0.5         0.75        1           1.25
0.1 0.876155737 0.888282356 0.904731158 0.910351368 0.906284762
0.2 0.810528369 0.797068044 0.806520168 0.805697704 0.80659234
0.3 0.696280633 0.704307378 0.703540949 0.705198518 0.708672067
0.4 0.601264163 0.605194    0.607882    0.611616655 0.612408848
0.5 0.502995372 0.509209974 0.513651558 0.516065068 0.51994982
```

(this is a tiny upper-left part of my "matrix", the first column being the beginning of `X` and the first line being the beginning of `Y` and the rest being the matrix, meaning by that that for instance `f(0.4, 0.75) = 0.607882`.

I naturally used a `pd.dataframe` as follows :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=Z, columns=Y, index=X)
df.to_csv(some_full_path_filename)
```

and indeed the csv file looks like I want it to look, that is, like the small bit of the matrix above.

Now if I

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(some_full_path_filename)
df2 .to_csv(some_full_path_filename2, index=False)
```

the second csv file looks like :

```
Unnamed:0   0.25        0.5         0.75        1           1.25
0.1         0.876155737 0.888282356 0.904731158 0.910351368 0.906284762
0.2         0.810528369 0.797068044 0.806520168 0.805697704 0.80659234
0.3         0.696280633 0.704307378 0.703540949 0.705198518 0.708672067
0.4         0.601264163 0.605194    0.607882    0.611616655 0.612408848
0.5         0.502995372 0.509209974 0.513651558 0.516065068 0.51994982
```

which is the closest to the first csv file I succeeded to get while trying myself with pandas. And of course, the two dataframes `df` and `df2` are not "equal".

Hence the question's title : an operation being *involutive* when applying it two times gives the starting value, then no, *my* "dataframe to csv file" and "csv file to dataframe" operations are not involutive.

To be precise there are floating point rounding differences in the dataframes and the csv files, like in one I could have `0.0072618782055291` in the matrix but in the other one at the same place I could have `0.0072618782055290999999999` : this is not a problem for me.

What I would like is *my* "dataframe to csv file" and "csv file to dataframe" operations to give dataframes and csv files structurally equal.

"Structurally" meaning :

- for the csv files : to have the same values (up to rounding) and strings (if any) in every "cell"
- for the dataframes : of course they won't be equal *per se* as they don't "point" to the same place in allocated memory but I would like them the be equal in the sense that all numerical/text values in them represent same numbers/strings (up to rounding for numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be difference, because in csv all data are saved like strings, so if use `index_col=0` here is correctly create `FloatIndex`, but columns names are strings, also data in columns should be parsed differently (e.g. if mixed strings and numeric):

```
f = 'file.csv'
df.to_csv(f)

df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0)
print (df)
         0.25       0.5      0.75         1      1.25
0.1  0.876156  0.888282  0.904731  0.910351  0.906285
0.2  0.810528  0.797068  0.806520  0.805698  0.806592
0.3  0.696281  0.704307  0.703541  0.705199  0.708672
0.4  0.601264  0.605194  0.607882  0.611617  0.612409
0.5  0.502995  0.509210  0.513652  0.516065  0.519950


print (df.columns)
Index(['0.25', '0.5', '0.75', '1.0', '1.25'], dtype='object')
```

Another idea is use `pickle`, [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html) and [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) for correct save DataFrames with columns and index:

```
print (df.columns)
Float64Index([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25], dtype='float64')

f = 'file'
df.to_pickle(f)

df1 = pd.read_pickle(f)
print (df1)
         0.25      0.50      0.75      1.00      1.25
0.1  0.876156  0.888282  0.904731  0.910351  0.906285
0.2  0.810528  0.797068  0.806520  0.805698  0.806592
0.3  0.696281  0.704307  0.703541  0.705199  0.708672
0.4  0.601264  0.605194  0.607882  0.611617  0.612409
0.5  0.502995  0.509210  0.513652  0.516065  0.519950

print (df1.columns)
Float64Index([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25], dtype='float64')

print (df1.equals(df))
True
```

Comment: Never heard of `pickle` before, and thanks a lot. Just a question though : in other languages, serialization (text one like xml or json as well as binary one) depend on library versions used to serialize etc. Meaning by that that if you deserialize something that someone else serialize with not the same code as yours, you obtain null. How does this work with `pickle` ? I won't have issues with python3/pickle versions upgrading or ?

Comment: @Olorin - Unfortunately no idea, sorry.